# Roblox badge not being rewarded on live game but does in studio

Tags: roblox

I have the following code in Roblox in a file under ServerScriptService and it gives a player a badge when they touch a specific part. It works on studio locally but once published its not working.

```
local BadgeService = game:GetService("BadgeService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local part = game.Workspace.Levels["040"].Spawn
local BadgeID = ########
local needBadge = true

local function awardBadge(userId, badgeId)
    -- Fetch badge information
    local success, badgeInfo = pcall(function()
        return BadgeService:GetBadgeInfoAsync(badgeId)
    end)
    if success then
        -- Confirm that badge can be awarded
        if badgeInfo.IsEnabled then
            -- Award badge
            local awarded, errorMessage = pcall(function()
                BadgeService:AwardBadge(userId, badgeId)
                print("Give player badge")
                needBadge = false
            end)
            if not awarded then
                warn("Error while awarding badge:", errorMessage)
            end
        end
    else
        warn("Error while fetching badge info!")
    end
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    part.Touched:Connect(function(p)
        print("touched:", player.UserId)
        if needBadge then
            awardBadge(player.UserId, BadgeID)
        end
    end)    
end)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you tested the game in studio and collected the badge, then you will have it when you test the game on the website.

Comment: Well, it does not work.